# How to set an inner text of HTML's element?

Tags: html

I would set the text of an HTML's element directly inside its markup.

I have tried to set the following attributes:

> innerHTML
>   innerText
>   textContent

Here the demo:

```css
button{
  height:20vh;
  width:20vw;
}
```

```html
<button innerHTML="innerHTML"
        innerText="innerText"
        textContent="textContent"
 />
```

How can I achieve the result to implement text from HTML's attribute?

Comment: `<button>text goes here</button>`. `buttonElement.textContent = 'text here';` in JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but those are not HTML attributes. They are `HTMLElement` properties and must be accessed via the API.

Comment: @EternalHour thanks for your answer, I would make something like the placeholder for input elements, which input some content inside the HTML element

Comment: @Webwoman check my example please

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it like this as an example:

```
<button type="button" id="myButton" class="custom_button">Here is your text</button>
```